# How to resolve python selenium webdriver error?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I installed selenium before 5 minutes. I wanted to try in IDLE, but i see some errors. How can i fix them properly ? What is the problem ?

What should I do to resolve this error? I did everything right, even copy and paste from the official site, but there is an error in the webdriver section.

````
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome()```

[!enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNzl5.png
````

Comment: @AvivYaniv i fixed this issue 5 minutes ago.from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver_path = r"C:\Users\canpi\Desktop\cnp\chromedriver.exe"

browser = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
browser.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(2)
browser.quit()

But now it isnt working

Answer (score 0):

try doing browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/Users/path/to/driver")
with the path to driver being where you have the Chromedriver.
That should get it working.